# My Timer is null but it's running

Tags: android

My program is appWdiget for android.
and there are 2 Timers as field.

```
Timer usualTimer;
Timer unusualTimer;
```

at only special time, i wanna run unusualTimer,
but i don't wanna run them at same time along with usualTimer,so i have code of checking null.

first, i get usualTimer run using Broadcast to sense appWidget was set on screen.

this is in my broadcast class.

```
//run  appWidget is set
    if(usualTimer == null){
                        usualTimer = new Timer();
                    motionTimerTask mtt = new motionTimerTask();
                    usualTimer.schedule(mtt, 0, 10000);
             }
```

next, i get unusualTimer run.
this is also in same broadcast class.

```
//run when catch special Broadcast
        if(usualTimer != null){
                            usualTimer.cancel();
                            usualTimer=null;
                        }


                        if(unusualTimer==null){
                        motionTimerTask mttU = new motionTimerTask();
                                usualTimer.schedule(mttU, 0, 10000);
    }
```

now, unusualTimer is running, usualTimer stops.

my problem is, in this situation, usualTimer starts running  when i **reset** this appWidget.
i don't know why (usualTimer == null) is true　nevertheless　usualTimer is running.

To unregist receiverthis is code in Service. is this a problem?

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
  unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

please tell me how to fix.

Comment: Please indent your code.